# Adding data to database from program. Android

Tags: android, sqlite, file

I faced with the following situation. In my program I have to keep files in database. This database contains title of the article which keeps file and path to the file. All files are kept in Assets folder and are created manually. But what if I want to add files from the program itself. For example to create a special edittexts where user can write title and articles. How can I keep this data? I understand how to add title,entered by user,to database,it's easy. But what about the articles. I can't place them with file which were created manually,as Assets can't keep such files. I thought to add all full articles to database,but how can I add asset's files in such case?

Comment: Hi, why are you not using the filesystem?. Moreover, Save the title in database, save the article content in database. then have a template in your asset folder, when user clicks on article widget just callup the data and render the template.

Answer (score 0):

Files (images, PDF'd. Word documents .........) are not structured data and serve little purpose being stored in the database (Full Text Search (FTS) an extension for SQLite is a different matter).

The recommended technique is to store some reference to the file (e.g. full path or perhaps file name (if all files are stored at a location that is discernible by the file name)) in the database. So when you locate/search and obtain a row you then use the file itself.

However, if the files average around about 100k or less then SQLite can actual be faster and thus it may performance wise, be better to store the files in the database.

- *Note the 100k based upon the link below.*

[35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html)

You would store files as BLOB's (byte arrays). You read them into a byte array and on Android, assuming java and that the byte array is named **my_byte_array** and that the SQLiteDatabase is db then :-

```
 ContentValues cv = new Contentvalues();
 cv.put("FILE_COLUMN",my_byte_array);
 ........ other cv.put's for the other columns
 long inserted_id = db.insert("The_Table",null,cv);
 if (inserted_id < 1) {
     .... code to handle row not inserted.
 } else {
     .... code to handle row inserted OK
 }
```

### WARNING

Files greater than **2M** will be impossible to easily retrieve as a **Cursor Window** is limited to **2M** of memory. Even **1M** may well cause issues and may be unusable at some stage if the App needs to be backwardly compatible as I believe that Cursor window's were restricted to 1M (not sure when).

### Retrieval from the database

To retrieve data from a BLOB you use the Cursor **`getBlob(column_offset)`** method, or generally better use the Cursor `getColumnIndex(column_name)` method to retrieve the column offset according to the column name. So if the Cursor is named  **csr** then** `my_other_byte_array = csr.getBlob(csr.getColumnIndex(column_name));`**

Noting that you have to **move** to a valid row before using the **`getBlob`** method.